# Simulate inline-block with CSS grid repeat but prevent occupying unused white-space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a number of DIV elements that I'd like to appear side-by-side (when screen resolution allows).  Previously, I used `display: inline-block` to achieve this.  However, the content of the DIV elements is dynamic, and it looks untidy when line breaks start to occur.

The CSS grid appears to be able to solve this, but there's a final piece of the puzzle I'm struggling with.

When using `repeat` with `minmax()`, unused white-space gets created as the div's expand to fill the empty space.  I need to prevent the div's expanding beyond the size of their content, because on large screens it makes the distance between them too great:

[image]

Is there any way to prevent the grid cells (or divs) expanding into the white-space?

1. The minimum space a grid cell should occupy is the size of it's contents
2. The maximum space a grid cell should occupy is a quarter of the screen
3. If the divs need to wrap, then they should sit inline with the grid lines

The SCSS is below, with accompanying [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/qBEoryW?editors=1100):

```
.SideBySideContainer {
    > div {
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding:1em;
    }
}

@media all and (max-width: 899px) {
    /* Small screens (will be improved to use @supports for grid support) */
    .SideBySideContainer {
        > div {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        > div:not(:last-of-type) {
            margin-right: 1em;
        }

        > div:first-of-type {
            max-width: calc(50% - 2em);
        }
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
    .SideBySideContainer {
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        grid-auto-flow: dense;
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(5em, auto);

        &.FourCols {
            /* Problem seems to be with minmax() here */
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 20%));
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Update - Issues with inline-flex

The suggested answer was to use `inline-flex`.  However, this looks ghastly when the content is lengthy, and causes two problems:

1. The content exceeds the container edges/boundaries
2. The divs don't wrap but get pushed off the screen

[Demonstration Link](https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/vYERrje?editors=1100)

Comment: can you please try with display flex concept.. it is allocating equal width window size

Comment: Can't do flex unfortunately because the neat wrapping aspect is essential, and I have no control over when that happens

Answer (score 1):

Setting max-width on the immediate-nested divs

```css
.SideBySideContainer > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
}

@media all and (max-width: 899px) {
  /* Small screens (will be improved to use @supports for grid support) */
  .SideBySideContainer > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .SideBySideContainer > div:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 1em;
  }

  .SideBySideContainer > div:first-of-type {
    max-width: calc(50% - 2em);
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 900px) {
  .SideBySideContainer {
    display: inline-flex;
  }
  .SideBySideContainer.FourCols > div {
    max-width: calc(100% / 4);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="SideBySideContainer FourCols">
  <div>
    <h3>Block 1</h3>
    <p>
      <select>
        <option val="">Foo</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Block 2</h3>
    <p>
      <select>
        <option val="">Bar</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Block 3</h3>
    <p>
      <select>
        <option val="">Foo Bar</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Block 4</h3>
    <p>
      <select>
        <option val="">Bar Foo</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check the snippet now

Comment: I updated my answer check it with - full page- because i modified only the min-900px

Comment: happy that you achieved it, but i have a question for you, why not to use bootstrap?

Comment: What element(s) of bootstrap would solve this problem?

Comment: ok, i forgot that you don't want to occupy the whole area you want only the content width, i updated my answer with your suggestion to help others in case they want to use the same code

Comment: There's a problem :(  If you shrink the screen width, the form elements expand outside the div.  I don't understand what is causing this... https://codepen.io/evildr/pen/gObeRYQ?editors=1100